# Validating form using php session

Tags: php, forms, validation, session

I am trying to validate my form using php. Upon validation it will give a welcome message.Or else it will redirect to the index page. I have used session to save the variable. But the problem is nothing happen's when I submit the form, Here's my script

```
<?php session_start();
    $_SESSION['reg'] = array();
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $passwd = $_POST['passwd'];
    $repasswd = $_POST['repasswd'];

if(empty($_POST)){
    header("location:register.php");
}
else
{
    if(empty($name)){
        $_SESSION['reg']['name'] = "Please enter name";
    }
    if(empty($email)){
        $_SESSION['reg']['email'] = "Please enter email";
    }
    if (empty($passwd)) {
        $_SESSION['reg']['passwd'] = "please enter a password";
    }
    elseif (strlen(passwd)>16) {
        $_SESSION['reg']['passwd'] = "At most 16 chars";
    # code...
    }
    if ($passwd != $repasswd) {
        $_SESSION['reg']['repasswd'] = "Passwords don't match";
    }
    if (empty($_SESSION['reg'])) {
        header("location:welcome.php");
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['data'] = array();
        foreach($_POST as $id=>$val)
        {
            $_SESSION['data'][$id] = $val;

        }
        header("location:register.php");
    }

?>
```

when I submit the form, It shows a blank page.

Comment: how about setting `ini_set('display_errors','on')` at the top of your page and then try

Comment: Doesn't do anything :( .. sould I place this before <?php ?

Comment: no, it should be after the `<?php` the second thing i'd suggest checking the php logs, i don't know why but sometimes I've encountered a similar scenario, blank page, no errors, it still gets logged though, so check there.

Comment: Thanks.. I found the error.. It was a bracket.. Nice suggestion , I am a beginner, silly mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not storing your post variables into the session if they are NOT empty prior to checking

```
if (empty($_SESSION['reg'])) {
```

I would highly suggest doing some sql injection prevention prior to putting post variables into the session scope.

UPDATE: So if you want the variable in the session scope, instead of checking `if(empty($name)){` and setting an error message in the session, I would do this:

```
if( !empty($name) ){
   $_SESSION['reg']['name'] = $name;
} else {
   // error handling
}
```

this will set the session variable if the posted value is NOT empty. Now when you check your session variable later on, it will have the name value in it and won't be empty.

Comment: I would do sql injection prevention later, but I don't understand what you are telling me to do..

Comment: If `(empty($_SESSION['reg'])) {` is true, I shouldn't store the post variables, It should just go to the welcome page.

Comment: I updated my answer with an example of how to set the session variable.